# Website authentication server restart

Tags: .net, authentication, iis-7, load-balancing, windows-authentication

I am experiencing an very strange problem in one of the company websites. Can you help ?

Details

We have an internal website. The authentication mode is windows hence it takes windows logins. It is served from two windows servers running Windows Server 2008 R2. And are connected with Network Load Balancer (Request Handling - Round Robin).

Every month there is a routine patching on the servers which leads to restart of the server (not at the same time).

When restart occurs, we get Authentication prompts and it continues to give the prompt even after giving a right credentials. Popup wont go.. plain and simple.

Now after few hours, it gets normal.

I am not sure what happens.

We have checked everything. IISlogs, Network Monitor Log, Load balancer log but no help as they seems equal to the other server which works fine.

Do you have any idea or any similar experience ?

Comment: "It seems" is a term you should avoid in all cases. I suggest you open a support case via support.microsoft.com and share all data you previously collected with Microsoft. There must be some significant differences, but obviously not everyone is familiar with the analysis skills.

Comment: Lex, I have done that.. Even Microsoft is not able to help. They have like 9 engineers working from directory service end, iis end.

Comment: That's almost expected. The usual approach by enterprises is to move servers one by one out of the load balancing cluster, patch and then add back. This, there will be less a chance to hit such issues.